# Do you know what happend when i invoke copy constructor on self?

Tags: c++

I do not know what happend when i invoke copy constructor on self. In my opinion, The copy constructor will allocate new memory space for the object, and then copy the data of the old object to the new memory space. So the address will change when i call `A(a)`, but it not.

```
class A {
public:
    A(const A& t) {
        std::cout << "sss" << endl;
    };
    A() {};
 };
int main() {
    A a;
    std::cout << &a << endl;
    a = A(a);
    std::cout << &a << endl;

}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be a matter of opinion. The object lives on the stack. It has the same address before and after.

Comment: If you did this same sequence of actions with `int`s instead of your own class, would you expect the address of `a` to change? It's the same reasoning that it doesn't change in this case either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a = A(a);` does create a new `A` by invoke copy constructor.

But you then copy(assign) the value back to `a`. and drop the temporary.

the `a` address is never changed. (there is no way to change it btw)